# Don't change Font of my App on changing font from Android Native Mobile Settings

Tags: android, fonts, font-family

What I need is I don't want the font of my app to change, when it is changed from Android Settings.

For Example:
If I have set Font **ABC** in my app and I set font **XYZ** from Android Settings. It changes the font of my application to **XYZ** as well. I don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set / use custom fonts to solve this issue.

Please follow this steps.

**Step1 :** Create “font” directory under resource folder

**Step2 :** Download and add fonts in font folder

**Step3 :** Now you can access / use inside your xml file directly

**For E.g :**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWelcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans_bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/str_hello"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Also you can access / use in programatically

```
textView.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(activity, R.font.helvetica_neue_medium)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set your own font in the app.
Calligraphy library by chrisjenx is exactly for this purpose so that you override system font in your app.
Below is the github link for calligraphy:
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: I downloaded this code and run the this code. When I changed the font from Android settings, all fonts got changed. Didn't work